# crunch/resource packaging with aapt in ant build uses cache from other projects

Tags: android, resources, duplicates, aapt

I have two android apps using a common library. Each project defines its own background images for the splash screen and a few others. These images have the same names in both apps.

When I build/run from eclipse, each app uses the correct background images. However, when I run my ant build file, the contents are mixed up when packaging resources and the same images are used for both applications.

I am sure there is a cache somewhere that I need to clear but I can't find it (running on MacOSX Lion).

I tried the `-f` option of `appt`, but still the same problem.

Anybody knows how to fix this?

Comment: Found the issue. The images of "project 1" were also in the res folder of the library project. When building "project 2" with eclipse, the correct images are used (app before lib). When using aapt/crunch, the lib res folder was processed first, and the images of the lib project was used.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand how you solved it?

Answer (score 9):

run "ant clean" before doing an ant build/release.

Comment: This wasn't sufficient for me: I needed to close Eclipse, too.

Comment: That shouldn't always be necessary, I mean, closing Eclipse. I don't know why it was, at a certain point.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have closed Eclipse before you run ant from the command line.

Comment: This wasn't sufficient for me: I needed to run "ant clean", too.

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse's menu go to Project -> **untick** Build automatically. Then from your Ant view, run `clean`, then `release`.